# Why values are not storing in the table when i have clicked Submit button?

Tags: django, crud

I have created a form for getting the value and placing it in the table. But whenever I click on Submit button, it doesn't store or give any error.It is simply staying in that page itself.

```
Model.py
    class Employee(models.Model):
    ename=models.CharField(max_length=120)
    eaddress=models.CharField(max_length=120)
    eemail=models.CharField(max_length=120)
    ephone=models.CharField(max_length=120)
    emobile=models.CharField(max_length=120)
    eid=models.CharField(max_length=120)
    egender=models.CharField(max_length=120)
    ehire=models.DateTimeField()
    edob=models.DateTimeField()

class Meta:
    db_table="employee"
views.py
    def employee(request):
        emp=Employee.objects.all()
        return render(request,'employee.html',{'emp':emp}) 
    def addemployee(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            emp = EmployeeForm(request.POST)
            if emp.is_valid():
                try:
                    form.save()
                    return redirect(employee)
                except:
                    pass
        else:
            emp = EmployeeForm()
return render(request,'addemployee.html',{'emp':emp})


addemployee.html:
    <form method="POST" action="add_employee">  
        {% csrf_token %} 
          {{emp.ename}}
          {{emp.eemail}}
          {{emp.emobile}}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to display your form errors in template. So update your view and template like this:

```
def addemployee(request):
    emp = EmployeeForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if emp.is_valid():
            try:
                emp.save()
                return redirect(employee)
            except Exception as e:
                raise e  # for debug purpose now
    return render(request,'addemployee.html',{'emp':emp})


addemployee.html:
<form method="POST" action="add_employee">  
    {% csrf_token %}
      {{ emp.errors }}  // it will render form errors
      {{emp.ename}}
      {{emp.eemail}}
      {{emp.emobile}}
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I am assuming your form is not validating because you have many fields like `eid`, `egender` etc which are required for saving it in Database. If you are using Modelform, then you can use `{{ emp.as_p }}` [as per form rendering documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/#form-rendering-options) for rendering form instead of `{{emp.ename}} {{emp.eemail}} {{emp.emobile}}`.

Comment: i tried {{emp.as_p}} also.Still the form is not storing also then the page is also not navigating to next page.It doesn't give any error also

Comment: i found the mistake now.It was in view file.I used form.save () but there is no form object i declared.after clearing that i get IntegrityError such as django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'ehire' cannot be null")

Comment: Yep, you are right. I also missed that part as well.

Comment: You need to render `ehire` field in form. If you don't want hire, then either you can make it nullable or use `auto_add_now=True`. More info can be found in documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield

Comment: i made it nullable but also it shows the same exception

Comment: if i make it into nullable,the exception doesn't come,but the date is not storing in the db.it shows null in db